# How to get session callback info? AWS - Cognito - JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, token, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the AccessKeyID and the SecretKey (ultimately to programatically input into a CRUD operation on dynamoDB with fine grained access control).

Anywho, there are many API calls to get the credentials like getCredentialsForIdentity(). However, these all require further params, which requires more api requests and more params and so on.

Ive found a way to log a Cognito user in, and then check if they are logged in on for a profile page, where it can display the email and username:

```
var data = { 
    UserPoolId : _config.cognito.userPoolId,
            ClientId : _config.cognito.clientId
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

window.onload = function(){
        if (cognitoUser != null) {
            cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
                if (err) {
                    alert(err);
                    return;
                }

            console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
            console.log(session.Credentials.AccessKeyId); //<--THIS DOESNT WORK

    cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
            }
        console.log(result);

            document.getElementById("email_value").innerHTML = result[2].getValue();    
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = cognitoUser.getUsername();  
    });                 
      });
    }
  }
```

`console.log(session.Credentials.AccessKeyId);` seems to be an invalid request. Im assuming there's some good callback info in the `session`, like the AccessKeyID and SecretKey, which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session.Credentials.AccessKeyId will not work since session's output is:

> e {idToken: t, refreshToken: e, accessToken: t, clockDrift: 0}

whereas AWS.config.credentials's output is:

[image]

Thus your code will be:

```
var data = { 
    UserPoolId : _config.cognito.userPoolId,
    ClientId : _config.cognito.clientId
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);
var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

window.onload = function(){
        if (cognitoUser != null) {
            cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
                if (err) {
                    alert(err);
                    return;
                }
            console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
            AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                 IdentityPoolId: _config.cognito.IdentityPoolId
            });
            AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
                 console.log(AWS.config.credentials); // * see above what your response will be
                 console.log(AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
                 console.log(AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to get the userpool programatically by a user that is signed in? or does it have to be hardcoded?

Comment: @FlightHoldings Not as far as I know since you have to identify with what userpool you want to work with. You can however get the AWS.config.credentials as soon as you authenticate a user - however for this you will need the username/email and login password.